# Unable to gather data on Angular from .Net Api

Tags: .net, angular, api

Well just started following a book of Angular & .Net api. Although copy everything same but getting an error
On the backend I've .Net core Api & on frontend Angular. I get weather app (.net standard app) data on to Angular host 4200 but getting an error, although backend server works & shows Weather app data without any error but on Angular side i get following error. What do missing here.

while run ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json

Error:

```
*Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 504 (Gateway 
 Timeout)

*ERROR HttpErrorResponseerror: "Error occured while trying to 
proxy to: localhost:4200/api/WeatherForecast"headers: 
HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}message: 
"Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/api/WeatherForecast: 504 
Gateway Timeout"name: "HttpErrorResponse"ok: falsestatus: 504statusText: 
"Gateway Timeout"url: "http://localhost:4200/api/WeatherForecast"__proto__: 
HttpResponseBase
defaultErrorLogger @ vendor.js:16907
```

Following are my angular script:

api.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

 @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

 getData() {
    return this.http.get('/api/weatherForecast').subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
    });
  }
 }
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './services/api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
 title = 'accounting-app';

  constructor(public apiService: ApiService){}

  ngOnInit(){
  this.apiService.getData();
 }
}
```

proxy.config.json

```
 {
  "/api": {
      "target": "http://localhost:5000",
      "secure": false
   }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: you are not passing correct URI in your get request this.http.get('/api/weatherForecast'), should be this.http.get('http(or) https://serverName/api/weatherForecast')

Comment: Still getting same error, although update as your advised 
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:4200/api/WeatherForecast').subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake. in fact I didn't mention the full route in the WeatherForecastController.cs:

Before
[Route("[controller]")],

Since I mentioned whole Api path that is:

[Route("api/[controller]")]

it works!